# Compose View instead of Native view for marker's info window

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using compose maps library to display clusters of markers. Now to display a custom info window adapter I want to use the compose. I have followed the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis) of interoperability of compose via **ComposeView**. but when I add the **ComposeView** inside the info window method I am getting this error of cannot locate window recomposer.

> Cannot locate windowRecomposer; View androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView{e560fcf V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} is not attached to a window

Here is my code snippet.

```
 clusterManager?.markerCollection?.setInfoWindowAdapter(object : InfoWindowAdapter {
    override fun getInfoContents(p0: Marker): View? {
        return null
    }

    override fun getInfoWindow(p0: Marker): View {
        val composeView = ComposeView(context).apply {
            setContent {
                Text("Hello World")
            }
        }
        return composeView
    }
})
```

So is there any way to use the compose function inside getInfoWindow()?

Answer (score 2):

So I found the workaround for this, not sure if this is the correct way or not. Any comments will be valuable.

So according to [ComposeView](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/ComposeView), the initial composition will only happen if the view is attached to the window or if the parent CompositionContext is set explicitly.

The way info window view work is that they do not attach the view to the window but create a bitmap from the view and display that bitmap.

This is also mentioned in the [ComposeInfoWindowAdapter](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/blob/main/maps-compose/src/main/java/com/google/maps/android/compose/ComposeInfoWindowAdapter.kt) of compose maps.

so following the example of ComposeInfoWindowAdapter you need a parent view to temporarily attach the ComposeView to the window and remove the parent view once the marker info window is rendered.

We are using the LocalView.current to get the current ComposeView. And creating the CompositionContext via rememberCompositionContext.

After doing this cluster manager's marker will support the compose function as the info window.

```
val currentView = LocalView.current
val compositionContext = rememberCompositionContext()

val markerCollection = clusterManager?.markerCollection
val infoWindowAdapter = ClusterItemInfoWindowAdapter((currentView as ViewGroup), compositionContext)
                    markerCollection?.setInfoWindowAdapter(infoWindowAdapter)
```

```
class ClusterInfoWindowAdapter(
    private val viewGroup: ViewGroup,
    private val compositionContext: CompositionContext
) : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private val infoWindowView: ComposeView
        get() = ComposeView(viewGroup.context).apply {
            viewGroup.addView(this)
        }

    override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View? {
        //Override this method if you want to set only content with default background
        return null
    }

    override fun getInfoWindow(marker: Marker): View {
        return infoWindowView.applyAndRemove(compositionContext) {
            MarkerContent(marker)
        }
    }

    private fun ComposeView.applyAndRemove(
        parentContext: CompositionContext,
        content: @Composable () -> Unit
    ): ComposeView {
        val result = this.apply {
            setParentCompositionContext(parentContext)
            setContent(content)
        }
        (this.parent as? MapView)?.removeView(this)
        return result
    }

    @Composable
    fun MarkerContent(marker: Marker) {
        //Show anything here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Compose has a way to change the info window for a marker, it depends on which Marker function you called.
There is `Marker` which will use Gmaps info window.
There is `MarkerInfoWindow` which will allow you to customize info window.
There is `MarkerInfoWindowContent` which will let you customize the content only for the info window.